# Calculating Machine Status Time in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a simple SQL express server set up and am logging data to it, I have multiple machines (industrial machinery) I am monitoring. Whenever the machines status changes I create a new record which enters data in the following columns. Time (Time Stamp), Machine Name (Text), Status (1,2, or 3) for running, idle, and down, and ReasonCode (1-10). I need to calculate how long the machine was in each status and also the reason for each status.  I would like to make this available via SQL reports. This is a function that A LOT of industrial manufactures are looking to do these days and I am trying to create a simple example. Unfortunately I am not that versed with SQL. I imagine this could be put in a stored procedure and run every n seconds to re calculate. Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: removed my answer since it doesn't address your root question - I misunderstood part of your explanation about your datatypes

Answer (score 3):

Assuming a table called `status` containing

```
MachineName NVarChar(whatever)
Status Int
Reason Int
Time DateTime
```

Then this query should work nicely

```
Select 
    st.MachineName,
    st.status,
    st.reason
    st.Time as TimeChanged,
    DateDiff(ss, min(dur.Time), st.Time)
From
    Status st inner join
    Status dur on st.MachineName = dur.MachineName and st.Time <dur.Time
group by
    st.MachineName,
    St.Status,
    st.Time,
    st.reason
```

Edit - in answer to your comment

```
select
    st.MachineName,
    sum(case when status=1 then Duration else 0 end) as RunningTime,
    sum(case when status=2 then Duration else 0 end) as IdleTime,
    sum(case when status=3 then Duration else 0 end) as DownTime,
From
    (Select 
        st.MachineName,
        st.status,
        st.reason
        st.Time as TimeChanged,
        DateDiff(ss, min(dur.Time), st.Time) as Duration
    From
        Status st inner join
        Status dur on st.MachineName = dur.MachineName and st.Time <dur.Time
    group by
        st.MachineName,
        St.Status,
        st.Time,
        st.reason) as foo
Group by MachineName
```

That should get machine name and a column for the time spent in each of the states

Comment: +1 Very nice solution. You do lose the current state but its possible to get that as well with at the least a union.

Comment: @Conrad - Good point, The join could be changed to `left outer` which should solve that, the datediff given one null argument would return null.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I see how these work and am playing with the code now to work and it is, is there any way to add up all the time the machien was up, idle and down, so I only create 3 rows in the output? like this

Comment: @Robb yep that'll do it. Its funny I thought of that with my solution but not yours.

Comment: I actually typed in the wrong area by mistake I could not get your code to work I get errors Level 15, State 1, line 9

Comment: OK I stopped being a total idiot and have your code working too. I need to remember to stop hitting enter!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to re-calculate. You can just query the info on demand. Here is a self contained example

```
DECLARE @Test 
Table (
    LogTime datetime, 
    MachineName varchar(100),
     Status int , 
     ReasonCode  int)

INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('01/01/2011 4:19:11.459'  ,   'ServerX',  1,  3)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('01/02/2011 3:43:03.652'  ,   'ServerZ',  0,  4)  
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('02/04/2011 11:17:51.827'  ,  'ServerX',  2,  2)  
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('02/05/2011 4:22:22.205'  ,   'ServerX',  3,  1)  
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('01/03/2011 11:42:44.211'  ,  'ServerZ',  1,  4)  



;with TIMEdelta AS (
SELECT 
    machineName,
    t.LogTime,
    MIN(nextTime) as nextTime 
FROM (
    Select 
        t.MachineName,
        t.LogTime, 

        t1.LogTime nextTime
    from @Test t
        INNER JOIN @Test t1
        ON t.machineName = t1.machineName
        AND t.LogTime < t1.LogTime

    ) t

GROUP BY
    machineName,

    t.LogTime

)

SELECT 
    t.MachineName,
    t.LogTime,
    t.ReasonCode,
    t.Status,
DateDiff(DAY, 0, (TIMEdelta.nextTime - TIMEdelta.LogTime) ) Days,
DatePart(HOUR , TIMEdelta.nextTime - TIMEdelta.LogTime ) Hour,
DatePart(MINUTE, TIMEdelta.nextTime - TIMEdelta.LogTime ) MInute

FROM 

    @Test t
    LEFT JOIN TIMEdelta
    ON t.LogTime = timedelta.logtime
        and t.MachineName = TIMEdelta.MachineName
```

This outputs

```
MachineName LogTime                 ReasonCode  Status      Days        Hours       Minutes
----------- ----------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
ServerX     2011-01-01 04:19:11.460 3           1           34          6           58
ServerZ     2011-01-02 03:43:03.653 4           0           1           7           59
ServerX     2011-02-04 11:17:51.827 2           2           0           17          4
ServerX     2011-02-05 04:22:22.207 1           3           NULL        NULL        NULL
ServerZ     2011-01-03 11:42:44.210 4           1           NULL        NULL        NULL
```

You could modify the output to display the current time - logtime instead of Null for those current state rows

**Update** For aggregates for pivot you can use PIVOT

```
  SELECT
 MachineName,
 [0] as Started,
 [1] as Stopped,
 [2] as Paused,
 [3] as Foo

FROM
(
SELECT 
    t.MachineName,
    t.status,
    cast(TimeDelta.nextTime - t.LogTime as DECIMAL(18,10)) duration

FROM 

    @Test t
    LEFT JOIN TIMEdelta
    ON t.LogTime = timedelta.logtime
    and t.MachineName = TIMEdelta.MachineName
) source
PIVOT
(
SUM(duration)
FOR status IN ([0], [1], [2], [3])
) AS PivotTable;
```

Which has this output

```
MachineName Started       Stopped        Paused       Foo
----------- ------------  -------------- ------------ ------------
ServerX     NULL          34.2907449846  0.7114627315 1.0000000000
ServerZ     1.3331082948  NULL           NULL         ULL
```

**Update** Used dates that crossed months and updated Days calc

Comment: OK I meant to ask this below but screwed up. Can the output be added so I get the total for each status so it would only output the total time each machine was in each state?